# How to insert calculated value with model in asp.net core?

Tags: asp.net-core, model

[Data table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzURv.png)

I'm very new on asp.net core. I have a concern is how we can insert value by default via model. Such as I have a table as picture attached.

I can get model auto-generated and insert by select Transaction_UserID but it's not practical as normally we will get current user logon ID and pass it as value to that field.

My questions are:

- How to implement to insert value generated by code not user via input form.
- How and on which part we will calculate that value

Such as my code to set is similar like this will not work as it will not allow property with only set.

//- Set user to first user by default
private long _TransactionUserId = 3;
public long TransactionUserId
{
set
{
_TransactionUserId = value;
}
}

Thank for your support in advanced.

Comment: How is your problem related to ASP.Net Core? I don't see the connection.

Comment: ·Transaction_UserID · is a drop-down list? and how do you calculate the value, where do you want to calculate it, in the view, or controller?

Comment: @Karney: yes normally it will automatically generated as dropdownlist with list of user in data table Users. But I don't want that way but it will get current logon user ID and pass that value when insert new records. But I don't know how to implement it.